# Create a temporary table in SQL on the fly

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I create a temporary table without first creating the columns?

```
CREATE TABLE #Yaks (
YakID int,
YakName char(30) )

select name
from tempdb..sysobjects 
where name like '#yak%'

drop table #yaks
```

It is a pain to have to define the table first.

Comment: The answer depends on the DBMS you're using (though I think it is MS SQL Server).  Please identify your DBMS in the tags (at least).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a (temp) table with the same columns as another (no data copied):

```
select * into #TempTable
from MyTable
where 1=0
```

Note: Does not create any Foreign keys, indexes etc...